# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException when running Project Hawaii Sample app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, reflection

I am using the Project Hawaii SDK to create Speech to Text application. I ran the sample project and upon starting the following exception was raised.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146232828
Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source=mscorlib
InnerException: System.MethodAccessException
   HResult=-2146233072
   Message=Attempt by security transparent method 'System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)' to access security critical method 'System.IO.File.Exists(System.String)' failed.
   Source=mscorlib
   InnerException:
```

I see the exception description however I am not able to find the appropriate solution. Here is the block code where the error occurred.

```
 try
        {
            bool fileExists = (bool)existsMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { configFilePath });

            if (fileExists)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> lines = (IEnumerable<string>)readLinesMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { configFilePath });
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        return line;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The summary of the function that is making these calls is " The function is used on a It looks for settings within specified file.  If it does not exist, it returns the default.The [SecurityCritical] sttribute is needed due to CA2140 analysis rules.